# How to convert cURL form login code to Swift

Tags: forms, swift, curl, cookies, nsurlsession

I am trying to login (form) into a website and parse data with `Swift` and `NSURLSession`.

I have been using cURL to confirm that this is actually possible, and the following code returns the webpage-body as expected.

```
curl -c cookie.txt -d "username=karl" -d "password=ivar" https://talkmore.no/talkmore3/servlet/Login
curl -b cookie.txt https://talkmore.no/talkmore3/servlet/SubscriptionUsage
```

When I am trying to do this in Swift, I fetch the Cookie from the response header, then I try to retrieve the `SubscriptionUsage`-webpage by passing the cookie along. However I cannot get this to work.

How can I convert this simple curl syntax to Swift-code using NSURLSession?

Edit: What I've got so far.

```
func login() -> Void {
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.talkmore.no/talkmore3/servlet/Login")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var params = "username=karl&password=ivar"

    request.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.addValue("text/html", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")
        println("Data: \(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)))")
        let httpResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse
        var cookie = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Set-Cookie"] as String
    })
    task.resume()
```

All seems good, I receive the response with a header including `"Set-Cookie" = "JSESSIONID=D8307BA498EFE061C86636C51B8AC25D; Path=/talkmore3/; Secure; HttpOnly";` And I believe I have to send this cookie with the next request. But I have failed to replicate the cURL behavior.

Comment: Could you show what you have written so far?

Comment: You don't have any code here that references `SubscriptionImage`  Show us what you've got for that since your question seems to imply that what you've got is worked as expected.  Perhaps check out [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSHTTPURLResponse/allHeaderFields) and [this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLRequest/allHTTPHeaderFields)

Comment: What I've already got does indeed work as you concluded. However the data returned from the session contains the body of the Login-page, not the SubscriptionUsage-page. How do I send a cookie with the next request to load the SubscriptionUsage-page?

Comment: So what keeps you from sending the next request with the cookie once you receive it?

Comment: Nothing keeps me from sending it, but whatever I send, I only receieve the body of the login page. How can I replicate the cURL behavior with Swift?